# Prestashop 1.7.5.2: bulk product combination not showing "Impact on price"

Tags: attributes, prestashop, combinations

I have added attributes to a product but on creating combinations the bulk process is only showing quantity and not showing "**Impact on price**".

I attached an image to give the clear picture of [what is required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmWmj.jpg), as editing the price for each and every combination would be very time consuming.

I also want to know how can we create **singe discount** for all the combinations, eg., a $5 discount for all the combinations.

[image: what is required]

Comment: [PrestaShop forums](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/) are probably the best place to ask your questions. Also, have you read [PrestaShop documentation and guides](https://www.prestashop.com/en/resources/documentations)?

Comment: You can upgrade to 1.7.6.4 or upper version. 1.7.6.4 has been fixed combination problems.

Comment: Hi,I am already using 1.7.6.5 and this is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom out on your browser to see the missing columns.